# Unmarshaling JSON in golang

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

i'm having a lot of trouble getting my program to work. I want to unmarshal something pretty simple, but it's giving me a lot of issues, unfortunately.

Here is the response that I want to unmarshal:

`{"error":[],"result":{"XXBTZUSD":[[1647365820,"39192.0","39192.0","39191.9","39191.9","39191.9","0.18008008",10],[1647365880,"39186.1","39186.1","39172.0","39176.0","39174.4","0.13120077",10]],"last":1647408900}}`

I've wrote these structs to help with unmarshalling

```
type Resp struct {
    Error   []string        `json:"error"`
    Result  Trades          `json:"result"`
}

type Trades struct {
    Pair    []OHLC          `json:"XXBTZUSD"`
    Last    float64         `json:"last"`
}

type OHLC struct {
    Time    float64
    Open    string
    High    string
    Low     string
    Close   string
    Vwa     string
    Volume  string
    Count   float64
}
```

I have a function call that makes the http request and then unmarshals the data. For whatever reason, my code will end before even starting the function call for the http request and subsequent unmarshalling when the Pair type is []OHLC or []*OHLC. If I change the Pair type to interface{}, then it runs. i want to make it work with the OHLC struct instead though. Below is the complete code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    //"strings"
    "io/ioutil"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Resp struct {
    Error   []string        `json:"error"`
    Result  Trades          `json:"result"`
}

type Trades struct {
    Pair    []OHLC          `json:"XXBTZUSD"`
    Last    float64         `json:"last"`
}

type OHLC struct {
    TT      float64
    Open    string
    High    string
    Low     string
    Close   string
    Vwap    string
    Volume  string
    Count   float64
}

/*func main() {
    var data = [...]Trade{
        Trade{5, "op", "hi", "lo", "cl", "vw", "vo", 2},
        Trade{5, "op", "hi", "lo", "cl", "vw", "vo", 2},
    }
}*/



func main() {
    fmt.Println("in main");
    getOhlc()

}

func getOhlc() {
    fmt.Println("in ohlc func")
    resp, err := http.Get("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XXBTZUSD");
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("error after request")
        return;
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close();

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body);
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("error when reading")
        return;
    }

    var jsonData Resp;
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &jsonData);
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("error when unmarshalling")
        return
    }

    if(len(jsonData.Error) > 0) {
        fmt.Errorf("error");
        return;
    }
    
    fmt.Println(jsonData);
}
```

Any ideas about what might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Any ideas about what might be happening?"*

The elements in the `"XXBTZUSD"` JSON array are arrays themselves, i.e. `"XXBTZUSD"` is an array of arrays. The `OHLC` type is a struct type. The stdlib will not, by itself, unmarshal a JSON array into a Go struct. Go structs can be used to unmarshal JSON objects. JSON arrays can be unmarshaled into Go slices or arrays.

You would clearly see that that's the issue if you would just print the error from json.Unmarshal:

> json: **cannot unmarshal array into Go struct** field
> Trades.result.XXBTZUSD of type main.OHLC

https://go.dev/play/p/D4tjXZVzDI_w

---

If you want to unmarshal a JSON array into a Go struct you have to have the Go struct type implement a the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17.8#Unmarshaler) interface.

```golang
func (o *OHLC) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // first unmarshal the array into a slice of raw json
    raw := []json.RawMessage{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &raw); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // create a function that unmarshals each raw json element into a field
    unmarshalFields := func(raw []json.RawMessage, fields ...interface{}) error {
        if len(raw) != len(fields) {
            return errors.New("bad number of elements in json array")
        }
        for i := range raw {
            if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(raw[i]), fields[i]); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    // call the function
    return unmarshalFields(
        raw,
        &o.Time,
        &o.Open,
        &o.High,
        &o.Low,
        &o.Close,
        &o.Vwa,
        &o.Volume,
        &o.Count,
    )
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/fkFKLkaNaSU

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It's taken me a while to understand it, but it's making sense now

Answer (score 1):

Your code had some issues:

1. Remove semicolons from end of lines, it's redundant.
2. `fmt.Errorf` return error, and not print it, every time check your error and propagate it.
3. We can convert array of numbers and string to struct in golang.

for achieving your desired output we need to first convert to intermediate container and then convert to our wanted output:

```go
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    //"strings"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Resp struct {
    Error  []string `json:"error"`
    Result Trades   `json:"result"`
}

type IntermediateResp struct {
    Error  []string           `json:"error"`
    Result IntermediateTrades `json:"result"`
}

type IntermediateTrades struct {
    Pair [][]interface{} `json:"XXBTZUSD"`
    Last int             `json:"last"`
}

type Trades struct {
    Pair []OHLC `json:"result"`
    Last int    `json:"last"`
}

type OHLC struct {
    TT     float64
    Open   string
    High   string
    Low    string
    Close  string
    Vwap   string
    Volume string
    Count  float64
}

/*func main() {
    var data = [...]Trade{
        Trade{5, "op", "hi", "lo", "cl", "vw", "vo", 2},
        Trade{5, "op", "hi", "lo", "cl", "vw", "vo", 2},
    }
}*/

func main() {
    fmt.Println("in main")
    err := getOhlc()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func buildOHLC(l []interface{}) (*OHLC, error) {
    if len(l) < 8 {
        return nil, errors.New("short list")
    }
    return &OHLC{
        TT:     l[0].(float64),
        Open:   l[1].(string),
        High:   l[2].(string),
        Low:    l[3].(string),
        Close:  l[4].(string),
        Vwap:   l[5].(string),
        Volume: l[6].(string),
        Count:  l[7].(float64),
    }, nil
}

func convert(r IntermediateResp) (*Resp, error) {
    result := &Resp{Error: r.Error, Result: Trades{Pair: make([]OHLC, len(r.Result.Pair)), Last: r.Result.Last}}
    for i, v := range r.Result.Pair {
        ohlc, err := buildOHLC(v)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        result.Result.Pair[i] = *ohlc
    }
    return result, nil
}

func getOhlc() error {
    fmt.Println("in ohlc func")
    resp, err := http.Get("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XXBTZUSD")
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error after request, %v", err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    if err != nil {

        return fmt.Errorf("error when reading %v", err)
    }

    var jsonData IntermediateResp
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &jsonData)
    if err != nil {

        return fmt.Errorf("error when unmarshalling %v", err)
    }

    if len(jsonData.Error) > 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("error")
    }

    convertedOhlc, err := convert(jsonData)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error when convertedOhlc %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(convertedOhlc)
    return nil
}
```

We define IntermediateResp and IntermediateTrades for Unmarshaling json and then convert it to actual Resp.

I think aother way is using custom Unmarshal for `Trades` struct.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This is a really interesting way to go about building the ohlc array. It always amazes me how many ways there are to get a similar end result